# $.each() on selects in page and get iterated options

Tags: jquery

I want to iterate all `<select>` s on page and get there `options`. I use code below:

```
$(function(){
  $('select').each(function(){
    $(this + ' option').each(function(){
       //can't access options
    });
  });
});
```

I get error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement] [option]
```

but this code works:

```
$(function(){
  $('select').each(function(i,v){
    $.each(v.children(),function(){
       //can access options
    });
  });
});
```

What is wrong with first code!
what is wrong with using `$(this +' option')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `this` in selector is object and you are using it as as string in selector to concatenate it, you can use `$(this).find` or pass `this` in context.

```
$(this).find(' option')
```

or

```
$(' option', this)
```

More straight forward way would be using [Descendant Selector (“ancestor descendant”)](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$('select option').each(
```

or [Child Selector (“parent > child”)](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) like

```
$('select > option').each
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select > option` selector.

```
$(function(){
    $('select > option').each(function(){
        //can access options
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use `children()` like this.

```
$(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
        $(this).children('option').each(function () {
            //can access options
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/xym0qh6f/)